# jquery dynamic checkboxes with data pass and mobile view

Tags: jquery, list, mobile, jquery-mobile, checkbox

i am in mobile app and i want to create dynamicaly list of checkboxes that passes some data to another function. I want this list of checkboxes look like mobile app

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html

and not as simple links...

here is my code

```
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            row = resultflatname.rows.item(i);

            if (row.flatdescription == flatdescription) {
                if (row.receiptno == 0){
                        items.push('<input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '" previous="' + row.pastpayments + '" barcode="' + row.barcode + '" todayp="' + row.todaypayments + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label></br>');
                allbarcode[i] = row.barcode;
                previouspayments = previouspayments + row.pastpayments;
                previouspayments = previouspayments.toFixed(2);
                sofeilon = sofeilon + row.amount;
                sofeilon = sofeilon.toFixed(2);
                total = total + row.amount - row.pastpayments;
                total = total.toFixed(2);

                } else {

                if ((row.receiptno > 0) && (row.todaypayments < row.amount - row.pastpayments)){
                        items.push('<input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '" previous="' + row.pastpayments + '" barcode="' + row.barcode + '" todayp="' + row.todaypayments + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label></br>');
                allbarcode[i] = row.barcode;
                previouspayments = previouspayments + row.pastpayments;
                previouspayments = previouspayments.toFixed(2);
                sofeilon = sofeilon + row.amount;
                sofeilon = sofeilon.toFixed(2);
                total = total + row.amount - row.pastpayments;
                total = total.toFixed(2);

                }
                }
            }
            list.html(items.join('\n'));

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing anchor elements to an array and joining them, wrap them in a list-item element before pushing to the array:

```
items.push('<li><input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '" previous="' + row.pastpayments + '" barcode="' + row.barcode + '" todayp="' + row.todaypayments + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label></li>');
```

Then when you join your table add the `<ul>` opening and closing tags:

```
list.html('<ul data-role="listview">' + items.join('') + '</ul>').trigger('create');
```

The `.trigger('create');` is important as it will make the jQuery Mobile framework initialize the new `listview` widget that you have just added to the DOM.

It's been a while since I used `.trigger('create')` so I can't remember if you can call it on a parent element (which I'm pretty sure you can) or if you will have to select the new `<ul>` element before calling `.trigger('create')`:

```
list.html('<ul data-role="listview">' + items.join('') + '</ul>').children().trigger('create');
```